# Refactoring creation of a binding from code-behind based to XAML based

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, relativesource

Today I'm using a constructor to receive an array and then bind it to the element.

C#

```
public MyDialog(Stuff stuff, IEnumerable<Thing> things)
{
  InitializeComponent();
  DataContext = stuff;
  MyComboBox.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding { Source = things });
  ShowDialog();
}
```

XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox"
          DisplayMemberPath="Canonic"
          Style="{StaticResource DefaultComboBoxStyle}" />
```

I'd like to refactor it into purely XAML based approach and I've approached it in the following way. However, I get no values in my combo box now and I'm very unsure how to trouble-shoot it.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox"
          ItemsSource="{Binding 
            RelativeSource={
              RelativeSource FindAncestor,
              AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
            Path=DataContext.TheActualThings}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Canonic"
          Style="{StaticResource DefaultComboBoxStyle}" />-->
```

Of course, the class *Things* contains a number of fields, one of which is called *Canonic* and contains a string to render as the option description. The control creating the dialog is of type *ProgramWindow* deriving from *Window*.

Please note that there's a similar question (as it may appear) but the difference is that in the other, I had syntax issue and once that's resolved, there's the actual technical problem described here. (I'm not giving a link to the other question because I prefer not to affect the view count on it.)

```
public partial class ProgramWindow : Window
{
  public ProgramWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
  }

  private void DataGridRow_OnDoubleClick(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs eventArgs)
  {
    MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(
      (sender as DataGridRow).Item as Stuff,
      (DataContext as ViewModel).TheActualThings);

    if (dialog.DialogResult ?? false) ...
    else ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code-behind for `MainWindow.cs` or `ProgramWindow.cs` to clear things up a little bit.

Comment: @Bahman_Aries I'll do that. However, in order to keep things tight and readable, I'd like to only post the relevant parts. What exactly would you need to see from the code-behind? I'll post the constructor and the creation of the dialog. Let me know if it's too much or too little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access the `DataContext` of another `Window` using a RelativeSource binding. The `RelativeSource` binding can only access elements within the same visual tree and the other `Window` cannot be accessed this way.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. I believe you're misled as to what my problem comes from - *TheActualThings* is **not a part of *stuff***, so I can't bind to it the usual way. In fact, if you view the constructor, you'll see that I need to provide parallelly (and call it *things* in the receiving parameter).

Comment: I also posted parts of the parent. Feel welcome to take a look - maybe that clarifies some of the confusion.

Comment: Since you have edited the question I now don't understand how it all fits together.

Comment: I suspect that your confusion is due to the assumption that I can bind to the data context's property *TheActualThings*. The problem is that I can't because it's not there. It's in the ancestor's *DataContext* and it's **that** context that I'm trying to get into (using XAML, instead of sending in the values via constructor).

Comment: I think the problem is that you are trying to access the DataContext of another Window? This is not possible as they are not within the same visual tree.

Comment: Oh, so the ancestry is **purely** within the markup (DOM or whatever it's called in WPF) of the same window? Add that to your reply. At the top. It's the answer, then.